# Java Jackson deserialization for id object that could be object or string

Tags: java, annotations, jackson

I am using Jackson to serialize id objects. The objects have the one field of id. Currently the code uses @JsonProperty over the field for serialization. The serialization looks like this:

"myId" : {
    "id" : "12345"
}

I would like to use @JsonValue over the getter so the serialization in the future would look like:

"myId" : "12345"

I need for this to be backwards compatible with the already serialized objects. Do I need to use a custom deserializer, or is there an annotation based strategy that will accomplish this?

Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to create POJOs that may be deserialized both from JSON Object and from JSON Scalar. For example:

```
public class Id {
  @JsonProperty String id;

  @JsonCreator
  public Id(String id) {
      this.id = id;
  }
}
```

As to serialization, you can choose either as-object (just getters), or as-String, latter using `@JsonValue`.